# If you autotune a PID while the controller is live what is the worst that can happen?

Tags: heat, pid-controller, plc

I am new to using PID in studio5000. I want to autotune a heater with a CV that stays at 100, never reaching the SP but just under it.

I think that might help the controller finally reach the SP.

What is the worst that can happen if I botch the autotune? [image]

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your field circuit which typically consists of OC OV protection to protect the device. In motor control industry, we've done what's commonly known as "bump" test where a step input is given to a large synchronous motor which probably cause some acceptable wear in the device but it never exceed the safety parameter of the "plant".
In your case however, Since its a heating element with much slower response rate (compared to a motor), I doubt it will break anything.

Comment: Thank you. The fuses were replaced for the controller and the CO stabilized at 47. I imagine the controller had to work harder because one line was not supplying power to the heater.

Comment: If you have a current feedback, add a supervisory control logic on top of your PID tuning code to limit the max current ( a software OC protection). Then you can run your autotuner without blowing off fuses. Ramp rate should not be an issue for a heating device however if you are using those "fast blow fuses" then you may also want to limit the ramp rate to safer limit. Start with lowest possible ramp rate and gradually increase it until you are satisfied with your system's response (or until you blow up another fuse).

Comment: We don't have current feedback at the moment but, we could integrate a current transformer in our setup. That would supply us with a current reading. The resolution might not be the best but it is better than nothing. 

 Thank you for the directions. I will investigate further how to implement them.

Answer (score 1):

If the heater has insufficient power to reach the setpoint (ie. CV is at 100%), **no** amount of fiddling with control parameters will fix it. You will need more control authority (ie. a more powerful heater), all other things being equal.

If the AT algorithm uses the (popular) relay method, you're unlikely to have any problems in a thermal control loop. It's essentially on/off control with some hysteresis. Extruders do have a lot of thermal input from shear in the plasticizing screw which can affect the controller tuning. In some cases the machine can be run almost adiabatically (minimal heating or cooling in each control zone).